Como puedo solucionar el este error en la installacion de docker desktop?
Me sale este error en la instalacion de docker, alguien me puede apoyar por favor
Unpacking failed: Data Error
en Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

¡Bienvenido Federico a la comunidad de Stack Overflow!
Parece que más de una persona se ha encontrado con este problema. Intenta ingresar este comando como administrador en el CMD: C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s.
Cabe aclarar que esta respuesta la he obtenido del lado angloparlante
